# how to properly define the tf.Variable if I have a number of blocks

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, deep-residual-networks

I just started to transform from pytorch to tensorflow, and have some problems when designing the residual blocks. I have a residual group which contain a number of residual blocks and eack block contains two custom layers. I am troubled with how to define the variables which needs to be used as a part of operation in call() function in each layer.

[image: this is a illustration of my model framework]

I tried to define the varible using like self.W = tf.Vaiable(). But in this way, when I initialize the residule group, the self.W will continously be coverd. And when I tried to use self.W to extrace this parameter in call function in each layer, I got None.

In pytorch, I can simply use register_parameters to define the variables in init, and use self.W to extract it in forward function.

Could anyone that are familiar with tensorflow can help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variables by using code below

```
class M(tf.Module):
  def __call__(self, x):
    self.v = tf.Variable(x)
    return self.v
```

Thank You.